# Google Maps API InfoWindow tied to last marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm trying to add an info window to each marker I put on the map. The info window is only displaying the last added marker. I have tried the other solutions on here but none have been working. Currently I'm doing this with the following code:

*(offending code starts halfway through at the comment //WORK IN PROGRESS)*

```js
function placeMarker(data, map){
var lati, lngi, title, details;
var image = 'image.png';

  for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
    console.log(data[i].eventLocation + " OF TYPE " + data[i].eventType);
    if(data[i].eventName != ""){
      title = data[i].eventName;
    }
    if(data[i].eventDetails != ""){
      details = data[i].eventDetails;
    }

      if(data[i].eventLocation == "Location 1"){
        lati = -29.651409;
        lngi = 82.342909;
      }
      else if(data[i].eventLocation == "Location 2"){
        lati = -29.637712;
        lngi = 82.368024;
      }
      else if(data[i].eventLocation == "Location 3"){
        lati = -29.650533;
        lngi = 82.342684;
      }
      else{
        lati = -29.645793;
        lngi = 82.347717;
        console.log(data[i].eventLocation + " not found");
      }
      // WORK IN PROGRESS
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: details
        });

      newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: lati, lng: lngi},
        title : title,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        details: details
      });

      newMarker.addListener('click', function() { //needs some work to connect to each marker instead of last one placed
          infowindow.open(map, newMarker);
        });
  }
}

function initMap(data) {
  var uluru = {lat: -29.643220, lng: 82.350427};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: uluru
  });
 // Marker Images
  var centerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -29.643894, lng: 82.354748},
    map: map,
    icon: image3
  });
  placeMarker(data, map);
}
```

Trying to find a solution has let me to displaying the last info entered on every marker, but not the correct info for the corresponding marker.
I changed this to this:

```js
newMarker.addListener('click', function() { //needs some work to connect to each marker instead of last one placed
          infowindow.open(map, newMarker);
        });
```

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'click', function() { //needs some work to connect to each marker instead of last one placed
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
```

Comment: make a variable var newMarker  = [] before for loop and then inside for loop use as  newMarker[i] = new google.maps.Mar...... and  newMarker[i].addListene.... do the same for infowindow too currently your objects are overridden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try my modification.. I can't debug your end but let me know if that works... if not, I guess that will help you to see the way that I use to iterate the loop and then fill empty array with all marker info, details etc and attach that event to maps..

```
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  // open info window
  var onMarkerClick = function() {
    var marker = this;
    infoWindow.setContent( marker.details );
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    mkmap.lastmarkeropened = marker;
  };
  // close the info window
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.close();
  });

  var marker = [] ;
  // loop start
  for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
    console.log(data[i].eventLocation + " OF TYPE " + data[i].eventType);
    if(data[i].eventName != ""){
      title = data[i].eventName;
    }
    if(data[i].eventDetails != ""){
      details = data[i].eventDetails;
    }

      if(data[i].eventLocation == "Location 1"){
        lati = -29.651409;
        lngi = 82.342909;
      }
      else if(data[i].eventLocation == "Location 2"){
        lati = -29.637712;
        lngi = 82.368024;
      }
      else if(data[i].eventLocation == "Location 3"){
        lati = -29.650533;
        lngi = 82.342684;
      }
      else{
        lati = -29.645793;
        lngi = 82.347717;
        console.log(data[i].eventLocation + " not found");
      }

      marker[ i ] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: lati, lng: lngi},
        title : title,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        details: details
      });

      // attach event to open info window
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker[ i ], 'click', onMarkerClick );
    } // end loop
```

see if this works..

cheers, K

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you so much for your help @oserk !

Comment: you have to put all inside your `details` for marker .. so I guess that you can alter something like: `details+=title;` and same for location :)

Answer (score 1):

Try placing it this way, defining this function before your loop:

```
var assignListener = function(markerObj, infoWindowObj){
                        return function() {
                               infoWindowObj.open(map, markerObj);
                                };
                      };
```

Then add the listeners via that function:

```
 newMarker.addListener('click', assignListener(newMarker, infowindow) );
```

Comment: I still get the same issue from my first attempted solution that now an info window displays on every pin; however, the last entered "details" are on every pin and not the unique pin to which it belongs